Docker SDK for Python - `mode` field in output of `Container.get_archive(path)` returning unexpected value when `path` is a folder
In the Docker SDK for Python, Container.get_archive(path) returns stat information of path in a dictionary.
However, when path is a folder, the  mode of the stat dictionary is set to 2147484141, which differs from running os.lstat(path).stmode (value of 16877).
The following code creates a container, a test file and a test folder:
import docker

client = docker.from_env()

container = client.containers.create(image='ubuntu:22.04',
                                     name='test_container',
                                     detach=True,
                                     stdin_open=True)
container.start()


# Creation of test file
container.exec_run('touch /home/test_file')

# Creation of test folder
container.exec_run('mkdir /home/test_folder')

# Data of file previously declared
bits, stat = container.get_archive(path='/home/test_file')
print("mode of file:", stat['mode'])

# Data of folder previously declared
bits, stat = container.get_archive(path='/home/test_folder')
print("mode of folder:", stat['mode'])

container.remove(force=True)

The output is:
mode of file: 420
mode of folder: 2147484141

I tried connecting to the container and replicating the results with the stat library.
For the file:
>>> import os
>>> from stat import *
>>> stat = os.lstat('/home/test_file')
>>> stat.st_mode
33188
>>> S_IMODE(stat.st_mode)
420

As we can see, the 420 matches with the value returned by Docker SDK for mode. According to stat docs, this is the result of the file’s permission bits, plus the sticky bit, set-group-id, and set-user-id bits.
But for the folder:
>>> import os
>>> from stat import *
>>> stat = os.lstat('/home/test_folder')
>>> stat.st_mode
16877
>>> S_IMODE(stat.st_mode)
493

The number 2147484141 is no where to be found.
Besides, when using stat functions with that mode, weird things happen:
>>> stat.S_IMODE(2147484141)
493
>>> stat.S_IFMT(2147484141)    # "Return the portion of the file’s mode that describes the file type"
0    # 0??? No portion of the file's mode?
>>> stat.filemode(2147484141)    # "Convert a file’s mode to a string of the form ‘-rwxrwxrwx’."
'?rwxr-xr-x'    # What's that '?'

TL;DR: Docker returns 2147484141 for a st_mode when using Container.get_archive(path), but that's not a valid mode. Also, it differs from the results obtained with the stat library.
What's happening? How does docker gets that mode field for the stat dictionary of Container.get_archive(path)?
